# Manipulate Periods using two tables in PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to manipulate the periods using two different periodic table and come up with one list of periods.

```
create table test_tbl1 ( 
department_id number  , 
department_type varchar2,
from_date  date ,
to_date date
) ; 


create table test_tbl2 ( 
employee_id number, 
department_id number  , 
from_date  date ,
to_date date
); 

insert into test_tbl1 values (1 , 'department_type1' ,  '01-jan-1990' , '10-Apr-2010' ) ; 
insert into test_tbl1 values (1 , 'department_type2', '11-Apr-2010' , '31-dec-4712' ) ; 
insert into test_tbl2 values (100, 1 , '01-jan-2009' , '31-dec-4712' ) ; 
insert into test_tbl2 values (100, 1 , '01-jan-2008' , '31-dec-2008' ) ;
```

I am looking for following output.

```
Employee Id | Department Type | form date | to date 
100           department_type1   1/1/2008   4/10/2010
100           department_type2   4/11/2010  12/31/4712
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select b.employee_id ,a.department_type , b.from_date , b.to_date
  from test_tbl1 a ,
       test_tbl2 b
 where a.department_id = b.department_id ;
```

This does not present the periods as your example because it is not clear what the logic related to them should be. You can always add something like:
`... GREATEST(a.from_date,b.from_date)...`

or the like if this type of relation is needed.

Comment: FDavidov, I did use greatest and least and its not returning the exact values as I expected. What I am looking for is that the department type with changed date according to employee information.

Comment: So, if what you want is the dates from the employee (regardless of those of the department), the query I posted should do the job.

Comment: I want the simple version of following query output.
select  Employee_id, department_type, greatest(tbl1.from_date , tbl2.from_date) , least(nvl(tbl1.to_date,'31-dec-4712') , tbl2.to_date) 
from  test_tbl1 tbl1 
inner join test_tbl2 tbl2 on tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID  
where tbl1.from_date <= tbl2.to_date and tbl1.to_date >= tbl2.from_date

Comment: however for this query, it helped your opinion to use the greatest ... thanks for that.